# Awaiting a single .NET event with a ValueTask

Tags: c#, .net-core, taskcompletionsource, valuetask

I have a simple `ITimer` interface that has just a classic `Elapsed` .NET event that is raised after the a certain timespan.

```cs
interface ITimer
{
    void Start(TimeSpan interval);
    void Stop();
    public event EventHandler Elapsed;

}
```

Now I would like to create a functionality that is similar to `Task.Delay(TimeSpan)` but it should use that `ITimer` abstraction instead of the "real" time. Also different form `Task.Delay(TimeSpan)` I though it might be a good idea to return a `ValueTask` instead of a `Task` because it could be implemented allocation-free and might generally be more performant. Also the completion of the delay only needs to be awaited once anyway.

Now a somewhat naive implementation could probably look like this. There problem here is, that there is no benefit of using a `ValueTask` at all. How could an implementation look like that takes full benefit of what a `ValueTask` promises (cheap and allocation-free).

```cs
ValueTask Delay(TimeSpan duration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // We get the ITimer instance from somwhere, doesn't matter for this question.
    ITimer timer = timerFactory.Create();
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    timer.Elapsed += (_, __) => { tcs.SetResult(true); };
    cancellationToken.Register(() =>
    {
        timer.Stop();
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
    });
    timer.Start(duration);
    return new ValueTask(tcs.Task);
}
```

Comment: I would expect this method to never be complete when you call it, so that would make this strictly worse than just returning a `Task`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Are you looking for [`ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.manualresetvaluetasksourcecore-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)?

Comment: "Premature optimization really the root of all evil" (Donald Knuth). I would be very careful optimizing things like this without good reasons to believe that this is an actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much has been written on `ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<TResult>`. It's essentially a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` but for `ValueTask<T>`.

It's really intended to be used *inside* a type like your timer, but you can [create a wrapper for it](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27558#issue-558423566) if you want to use it as an external method:

```
public sealed class ManualResetValueTaskSource<T> : IValueTaskSource<T>, IValueTaskSource
{
  private ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T> _logic; // mutable struct; do not make this readonly

  public bool RunContinuationsAsynchronously
  {
    get => _logic.RunContinuationsAsynchronously;
    set => _logic.RunContinuationsAsynchronously = value;
  }
  public void Reset() => _logic.Reset();
  public void SetResult(T result) => _logic.SetResult(result);
  public void SetException(Exception error) => _logic.SetException(error);

  short IValueTaskSource.Version => _logic.Version;
  short IValueTaskSource<T>.Version => _logic.Version;
  void IValueTaskSource.GetResult(short token) => _logic.GetResult(token);
  T IValueTaskSource<T>.GetResult(short token) => _logic.GetResult(token);
  ValueTaskSourceStatus IValueTaskSource.GetStatus(short token) => _logic.GetStatus(token);
  ValueTaskSourceStatus IValueTaskSource<T>.GetStatus(short token) => _logic.GetStatus(token);

  void IValueTaskSource.OnCompleted(Action<object?> continuation, object? state, short token, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags) => _logic.OnCompleted(continuation, state, token, flags);
  void IValueTaskSource<T>.OnCompleted(Action<object?> continuation, object? state, short token, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags) => _logic.OnCompleted(continuation, state, token, flags);
}
```

You can then use it as such (cancellation removed for simplicity):

```
ValueTask Delay(TimeSpan duration)
{
  ITimer timer = timerFactory.Create();
  var vts = new ManualResetValueTaskSource<object>();
  TimerElapsed eventHandler = null;
  eventHandler = (_, __) =>
  {
    timer.Elapsed -= eventHandler;
    vts.SetResult(null);
  };
  timer.Elapsed += eventHandler;
  timer.Start(duration);
  return new ValueTask(vts);
}
```

Note that, since this is an external method, you'd still be allocating the `ManualResetValueTaskSource<T>` (as well as the delegate). So this doesn't really buy you anything, and I would choose to use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` here. This is especially true when you add `CancellationToken` support and have to handle the race condition between the timer firing (`vts.SetResult`) and the cancellation (`vts.SetException`), since I'm pretty sure only one of those is supposed to happen per ValueTask operation, and there's no `Try*` variants in our `ManualResetValueTaskSource<T>` like `TaskCompletionSource<T>` has.

`ValueTask` is really intended to be more of a first-class citizen; i.e., ideally you would update the actual timer implementation (and interface) to support `ValueTask Delay(TimeSpan)` in its own class instead of an external method. Inside the timer instance, it can reuse the `ValueTask` backing type (`ManualResetValueTaskSource<T>`), it can know when to call `Reset`, and it can avoid the delegate/event completely.

Comment: I was trying to avoid adding an additional method `Delay()` to the `ITimer` abstraction because I though that this functionality can be be built on top of  the current very simple `ITimer` abstraction. But I guess this would come at the cost of performance?

Comment: @bitbonk: Yes, that's the tradeoff. For timers, though, I think `Task` is fine. I wouldn't expect it to be called often enough with a short enough delay that it would be worth optimizing that allocation.

Comment: That makes me wonder though, why they chose to make `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync` to return a `ValueTask`.

Comment: I think the reasoning there is that there are many `IAsyncDisposable` types that do not have any actual disposal at all. `IAsyncDisposable` was avoided for years but finally added for `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` (which *requires* asynchronous disposal). Most `IAsyncDisposable` types are async streams (at least right now), and most async streams do not require disposal. So those `IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync` methods will complete synchronously, and `ValueTask` avoids an allocation in that case.